# ethers read WETH allowance throwing call revert exception

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to read the WETH allowance of an account on blast (blast.io).
So far I have tried different ABIs but all of them result in errors.

```typescript
      const WETH_ADDRESS = "0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000004";

      const WETH_ABI_ALLOWANCE = [
        "function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256 result)",
      ];

      const wethContract = new ethers.Contract(WETH_ADDRESS, WETH_ABI_ALLOWANCE, signer);
      const address = await signer.getAddress();
      const allowance = await wethContract.allowance(address, "0x2cb41A98b6b01e50308AEDD754138510e2225933");
```

I've also tried with the json-ABI from https://github.com/banteg/baseline-looper/blob/main/contracts/weth.json, same result

The error is as follows:

```
Error: call revert exception (method="allowance(address,address)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)
```

Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vzxtek?file=app%2Fpage.tsx

Comment: I've executed it. Working fine for me though. What RPC are you using ?

Comment: Was a mistake with the chain config, closing @SYEDASADKAZMI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong blast network, turns out there are two and I got the wrong one.